# Having trouble getting the forms javascript working within foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, zurb-foundation

I am attempting to run foundations custom forms javascript and keep running into type errors. The errors are

> forms could not be initialized; TypeError Cannot call method 'indexOf'
>   of undefined"

I can't seem to figure out why this error is being thrown. It looks like this piece of code is the culprit

```
return arr.indexOf(item) === idx; around line 272
```

the arr object is null when it attempts to run this code. not sure if this is a result of something else going wrong earlier in the script or what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> the arr object is null when it attempts to run this code

That's exactly what the error is complaining about.

You need to fix the code to either make sure that `arr` is not null, or avoid using it when it is null.

Comment: I understand that is where the error is coming from however it seems like it might be something else that is actually causing it to be null. This is part of the foundation library; i looked at their bug tracker and nobody else appears to have this problem which leads me to believe its something I am doing wrong. Although other elements like the orbit slider work fine.

Comment: @user398314: We have no idea whether you're doing something wrong; we don't know anything about what or how you're doing.

Comment: Yea sorry about that, unfortunately i don't have a place setup for public viewing of this site. Basically I am integrating this within a magento website. (magento uses prototype so jquery no conflict is being used not sure if that has anything to do with it.) if you have any questions let me know and i will try and answer as best i can

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, I just came across this. This is a Prototype.js conflict. Basically, Prototype < 1.7.1 doesnt do a ployfill for `Array.filter` and Prototype's version of the method seems to not pass the third argument, which is the `arr` thats `undefined`. So you can do a couple things to work around:

1. Upgrade Prototype to 1.7.1 - this is what I did but I haven't thoroughly tested it across Magento yet so there could be issues... Its a minor point release, *what could possibly go wrong?* :-)
2. Adjust the Foundation code block so that you get the list of classes compiled in a var before hand, then you can reference it inside the callback to filter:

   ```
     // OLD
     $customSelect = $('<div class="' + ['custom', 'dropdown', customSelectSize].concat(copyClasses).filter(function (item, idx, arr) {
       if (item === '') return false;
       return arr.indexOf(item) === idx;
     }).join(' ') + '"><a href="#" class="selector"></a><ul /></div>');

     //-----------------
     // NEW
     var classList = ['custom', 'dropdown', customSelectSize].concat(copyClasses);
     $customSelect = $('<div class="' + classList.filter(function (item, idx, arr) {
       if (item === '') return false;
       arr = typeof arr === 'undefined' ? classList : arr;
       return arr.indexOf(item) === idx;
     }).join(' ') + '"><a href="#" class="selector"></a><ul /></div>');
   ```
3. You could attempt to override the Prototype version of `Array.filter` to pass the Array as the third argument. I'm not totally sure where this lives, I looked for it as that was my first inclination to mitgate risk but i eventually just decided to upgrade.